# doctrine select in new object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to select multiples objects in a single array result, but i cant see how to select it ...

Well actually I have this DQL:

```
    $dql = ' SELECT  obj AS Object1, objExternalRef AS Object2 FROM MyEntity1 AS obj
    INNER JOIN obj.objChild AS objChild
    INNER JOIN MyEntity2 AS objExternalRef WITH objExternalRef.objChild= objChild

    WHERE something
    ';

    $result = $em->createQuery($dql)
    ->setParameter( ... )
    ->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, 1)
    ->getResult();
```

returning this array[ Object1 , Object2, Object1, Object2, ... ]:

```
  {
    "Object1": {...}
  },
  {
    "Object2": { ...}
  },
```

And i would like to encapsule this in a new object containing theses 2 objects like:

```
{
   "Object1" : { ... },
   "Object2" : { ... }
},    
{
   "Object1" : { ... },
   "Object2" : { ... }
},
```

I think I need to make a select of this select(query) to group theses 2 object in a new object, but i can't figure out how to make it.

I also know that if i just make a for($i = 0; i < sizeof($result); i += 2) i can concat these 2 objs in a new one, but I don't think this is so far a nice fix.

Can someone give-me a light here?

Comment: You could use a [DTO](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#new-operator-syntax) has a *helping vehicle*.

Comment: The DTO is really nice, but on documentation, its say "**Note that you can only pass scalar expressions to the constructor.**". My Case I need the full object and child's, if i try to force DTO constructor to accept my Entity it's throw error **Argument 1 passed to testDTO::__construct() must be an instance of LojaProdutos, integer given** so by what I saw I will have a well big constructor in my DTO kkk, I'm right or have other way?

Comment: That seems the case, but it depends on what you'll be using this DTOs for. If, by chance, you don't always need all of them hydrated, you could select only the pk for the given entity. And than later hydrate them lazily.

Comment: Nice!, So I can pass the pk to DTO and on constructor call a **em->getReference("Entity", pk) and hydrate this**. my last question is: this will not have a heavy overload on database (make the search twice, first for get results and second to hydrate each result) or it will hydrate from cache?

Comment: I'm not sure this will work. Currently you'd have no way to pass the entity manager to each constructor. So after all you'd probably end with the same thing you wanted to avoid (packing the objects inside some loop). It's really only useful if you don't actually need to hydrate each and every DTO. And you'd still need an extra hydrator with access to the entity manager.

Comment: Of course you could go *all fancy* and actually implement your own [custom hydrator](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#custom-hydration-modes). But it really depends whether this adds anything useful to your application. If this is a one time use and a loop would do, use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If these two objects are related good practice will be to define this association mapping ie one to many or many to one in your entity relationship. For example

In country entity/object --(of course also defined on state side)

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="State", mappedBy="stateCountry")
 */
private $states;
```

You can simply do a

```
$country->getStates()
```

See [Doctrine Association mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) for more

However if they are not and you want mixed results you will need to use result set mapping/scalar results. I usually use native queries for something like this.  For example

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addScalarResult('name', 'name');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('id', 'id');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('slug', 'slug');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('num', 'num');


    $sql = "SELECT f.name, f.id, f.slug, COUNT( t.demo_id ) AS num FROM tag_demos t LEFT JOIN tag f ON f.id = t.tag_id " .
            " GROUP BY t.tag_id ORDER BY COUNT( t.demo_id ) DESC LIMIT 20";

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
    return $query->getResult();
```

See [Native Query-Result Set Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) for more examples.